# What do these symbols mean?

Tags: airport, airport-markings

[image]

What do these symbols mean in an airport?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please provide context, like *where* did you see it? A clearer title will help others looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is stated in [ICAO Annex 12 (Search and Rescue)](http://panorama.abear.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ICAO-Annex-12-Search-and-Rescue.pdf)<sup>PDF</sup>. (See Appendix I relevant to Chapter 5, 5.8 of the Annex.)

Ground-air visual signal code for **use by survivors:**

[image: G/A used by survivors]

Ground-air visual signal code for **use by rescue units:**

[image: G/A used by rescue units]

> Note 1.— Symbols may be formed by any means such as: strips of fabric, parachute material, pieces of wood, stones or such like material; marking the surface by tramping, or staining with oil.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Very interesting.  In "Use of Weapons", Iain M Banks adapts this kind of signalling.  Zakalwe marks his location for airborne pickup on a battlefield by making a Z - by arranging bodies...